# Python TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Tags: python, hash, encoding, typeerror

I have looked at the other 4 questions on here but still cannot figure out where to put the `.encode()` or `.encode('utf-8')`.  I have commented it out to show the various places I have tried.

```
import hashlib as hasher

    class Block:
        def __init__(self, index, timestamp, data, previous_hash):
            self.index = index
            self.timestamp = timestamp
            self.data = data 
            self.previous_hash = previous_hash #these four items used to calculate crypHash of each block
            self.hash = self.hash_block() #helps ensure integrity throughout blockchain

        def hash_block(self):
            sha = hasher.sha256() #.encode('utf-8')
            sha.update(str(self.index)+
                str(self.timestamp)+
                str(self.data)+
                str(self.previous_hash)) #.encode() inside brackets
            return sha.hexdigest()
```

Here is the Traceback (reading bottom up):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blockchain.py", line 7, in <module>
    blockchain = [create_genesis_block()]
  File "/media/nobu/win10Files/Blockchain/SnakeCoin/genesis.py", line 8, in create_genesis_block
    return Block(0, date.datetime.now(), "Genesis Block", "0")
  File "/media/nobu/win10Files/Blockchain/SnakeCoin/block.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.hash = self.hash_block() #helps ensure integrity throughout blockchain
  File "/media/nobu/win10Files/Blockchain/SnakeCoin/block.py", line 16, in hash_block
    str(self.previous_hash))
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

which seems to indicate that the line `str(self.previous_hash)) #.encode() inside brackets` should be `str(self.previous_hash).encode())` but that gives me this other error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blockchain.py", line 7, in <module>
    blockchain = [create_genesis_block()]
  File "/media/nobu/win10Files/Blockchain/SnakeCoin/genesis.py", line 8, in create_genesis_block
    return Block(0, date.datetime.now(), "Genesis Block", "0")
  File "/media/nobu/win10Files/Blockchain/SnakeCoin/block.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.hash = self.hash_block() #helps ensure integrity throughout blockchain
  File "/media/nobu/win10Files/Blockchain/SnakeCoin/block.py", line 16, in hash_block
    str(self.previous_hash).encode())
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

So I tried `encode()` and `decode()` in various combinations with brackets but that only gets me alternating between errors.
Thus, I am quite lost and would appreciate some guidance.
Btw this code is from a Medium article here:  [Medium Snake Coin](https://medium.com/crypto-currently/lets-build-the-tiniest-blockchain-e70965a248b)

Comment: Concatenate the entire string before encoding: `sha.update((str(self.index) + str(self.timestamp) + str(self.data) + str(self.previous_hash)).encode())`. `update()` takes a string. This may help: https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `bytes` strings can be hashed.  `str` is a Unicode string.  Encode to bytes, decode to Unicode.

In your `.update()`, all four items are being converted to `str`.  So once you concatenate them together, `.encode()` the whole thing to `bytes`:

```
import hashlib as hasher

class Block:
    def __init__(self, index, timestamp, data, previous_hash):
        self.index = index
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.data = data 
        self.previous_hash = previous_hash #these four items used to calculate crypHash of each block
        self.hash = self.hash_block() #helps ensure integrity throughout blockchain

    def hash_block(self):
        sha = hasher.sha256()
        to_hash = str(self.index) + str(self.timestamp) + str(self.data) + str(self.previous_hash)
        sha.update(to_hash.encode())
        return sha.hexdigest()
```